# Powershell script to sum up files inside a folder. Give me foldername and Filecount

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Me again :) , I am still learning but getting better slowly

This time I am  on a script to collect files inside a folder BUT the 2 upper folder names i can't know. So i have a double wildcard first.

What I need is : Display the number of files inside the configurations folder and name me both folders before.

perfect would be like this :  ...\folder1\folder2\configurations\  number of files : 3

My script so far works fine but it simply gives me a long list and if i have 50 items in one folder than it's too much.

```
$sumconfigs = (get-childitem -recurse "C:\appfolder\data\*\*\configurations" | where-object {$_.Name -ne "configuration.zip"} | Where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $false})

foreach ($config in $sumconfigs)
{
write-host $config.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your folder list first, then recurse into them:

```
Get-Item 'C:\appfolder\data\*\*\configurations' | % {
  $dir = $_.FullName
  $cnt = Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse | ? {
           $_.Name -ne 'configuration.zip' -and -not $_.PSIsContainer
         } | Measure-Object | select -Expand Count
  if ($cnt -gt 0) { "{0} number of files: {1}" -f $dir, $cnt }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I could use it very well and reworked it a bit. But I was not able to avoid displaying folder with 0 result. (or at least zero non "configuration.zip" . Do you know how to achieve that ?  i tried count -gt 1 etc. :/

Comment: @RayofCommand Simply put the output in a conditional. See updated answer.